# Local variable Table In JVM Stack

Tags: java, jvm, local-variables

Today I compile a class to bytecode, and I can't find anything in main method local variable table index 0, It's start from 1, I know a non-static method start 1 because it's 'this' at 0.

Here is the bytecode.

```
  // this is the main method
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1   // index: 1 (what is content at index 0 ?)
       2: iconst_2
       3: istore_2
       4: return

  // this is a static method
  public static void staticMethod();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_0  // index: 0 (no 'this')
       2: iconst_2
       3: istore_1
       4: return

  // this is a non-static method
  public void nonStaticMethod();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1  // index: 1  (index 0 should be 'this')
       2: iconst_1
       3: istore_2
       4: return
```

Help me please, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The local variable at index 0 in the `main` method is the method's argument: a reference to `String[]`. From the JVM specification:

> The Java Virtual Machine uses local variables to pass parameters on method invocation. On class method invocation, any parameters are passed in consecutive local variables starting from local variable 0.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1

Comment: Oh, I understand, thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: It’s worth noting that the compiler is not required to retain the pre-initialized variables, so since the code in question does not use the parameter nor this, the code could have re-used the variable index zero in all example methods (the typical compiler implementations don’t do this).